# Angular accessing a list of child components in a ng-container

Tags: angular

I have the following template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let object of objects">
   <child-component [input]="object "> </child-component>
   <input type="number" id="numvalue">
</<ng-container>
```

Is there any way to access my child components along side the input values. I tried using ViewContainerRef but cant seems to access child components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cycle `AfterViewInit` we query for all of our children marked with `#child` and we then `console.log()` property `input` of that child (please check console).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('child') childs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  objects: string[] = ['first', 'second', 'thrid'];

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.childs.forEach((child: any) => {
      if (child.input) {
        console.log(child.input);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let object of objects">
  <input type="number" id="numvalue"/> {{object}}
  <app-child-hello [input]="object" #child></app-child-hello>
</ng-container>
```

The child

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{input}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() input: string;
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xh3kil?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can I use the elementRef on ng-container so that I can access the child component and the associated input value

Comment: No, ng-container itself can't be accessed, it won't be rendered in DOM. It's only used for template variable `*ngFor` in this case. I have provided you a way to access child elements. Instead of using `child.input` on the elementRef you could `console.log(child.nativeElement)` to access the element in the DOM or just `console.log(child)` to access the child elementRef.

Comment: nativeElement is always returning null

Comment: Read it as `@ViewChildren('child',{read: ElementRef}) childsNative: QueryList<ElementRef>` then use `console.log(child.nativeElement)` I have updated the demo to include this.